# RoutedCommands propagation strategy

Tags: wpf, routed-commands

I'm a newby of WPF, and 'm trying to unserstund RoutedCommands.
RoutedCommands starts from command source, than event is propagated vua bubbling and tunneling.

But can i stop the process? for example i would like set CanExecute = false and than stop event propagation.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you try to stop a `RoutedCommand` to bubbling up the visual tree when your `CanExecute`-Handler sets `CanExecute` to `false`? If yes, try the following:

Set `e.Handled = true`. Make sure that the `CommandTarget` is set correct so that your `CanExecute`-Handler really is called. 
This is important, if you place your command in a `ContextMenu`. If no `CommandTarget` is specified, WPF will take the focused element and your `CanExecute`-Handler will not always be called and therefore possibly interpreted by another handler. 
Something like the following will do the job:

```
 <ContextMenu>
  <MenuItem Command="DesiredCommand" CommandTarget="{Binding PlacementTarget,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" .../>
  ...
 </ContextMenu/>
```